# Remove folders maching pattern recursively in Windows

Tags: windows

I need to delete all sub-folders in a folder tree that match the pattern "images".
I can remove all files matching a pattern using

```
del /s myfolder\images*.*
```

but it doesn't work for directories.
I tried with rmdir too but without success

Comment: `rmdir -r` works in my OS - but you did tag as Windows... The `-r` flag means "recursively". To force deletion you add `f`, so `rmdir -rf`. VERY dangerous command...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`rmdir /s` may be what you want to purge a sub-tree, and, as Floris said, this is very dangerous.  If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to delete `myfolder\a\b\c\holiday_images` while leaving `myfolder\a\b\c\holiday_videos` intact. 
This should do what you want:

```
for /d /r %i in (*image*) do @rmdir /s "%i"
```

This is native Windows functionality; no need to download or install anything.

A bit of general advice for running potentially dangerous commands like this
is to do

```
for /d /r %i in (*image*) do @echo rmdir /s "%i"
```

first;
that will show you what it will do, but not do anything. 
After you verify that it’s doing what you want, run it again without the `echo`.

If you want to use this command in a batch file (script),
you must double the percent characters; i.e.,

```
for /d /r %%i in (*image*) do @rmdir /s "%%i"
```

Comment: @EricL: Thanks for catching that. I know to use quotes in shell commands (and, in fact, I’m continually telling people to do it), but I keep forgetting to do it in CMD.

Comment: Here's how to show each dir being deleted as it's deleted.
`for /d /r %%i in (DIV_sv*) do (
 @rmdir /s /q "%%i"
 echo Removed "%%i"
 )
`
First paren must be on same line as do right after do, and rmdir command must be on next line.

Comment: @Bulrush: Yes, but (1) It works better if you put `@` before the `(`, and (2) You need either a `&` or an (Enter) before the `echo`. Also, as you have noticed, comments don’t allow you to display multi-line commands well. It helps if you enter separate lines as separate code strings; for example, \`line 1\` / \`line 2\` / \`line 3\` displays as `line 1` / `line 2` / `line 3`.

Comment: Also, why did you use a different pattern (`DIV_sv*`)  than the one in the question?

Comment: @Scott-СлаваУкраїні Kudos for pointing out '@echo'

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to show each dir being deleted as it's deleted.

```
for /d /r %%i in (DIV_sv*) do (
    @rmdir /s /q "%%i"
    echo Removed "%%i"
    )
```

First paren must be on same line as do right after do, and rmdir command must be on next line.

Answer (score -1):

rm -rf myfolder/images will delete without asking otherwise you can go -ri to confirm every deletion.

Comment: Ok i have "rm" from GnuWin32 package. However it won't delete the subfolder "myfolder\subfolder1\images". It only removes folders named "myfolder\images1", "myfolder\images2", etc (using asterisk: "rm -rf myfolder\images*")

Comment: rm -rf myfolder/images/* will remove all files in images, but rm -rf myfolder/images should remove that folder and all of its contents